# Can not execute SonarQube analysis from Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to configure Sonarqube analysis from Jenkins (using Maven). I have Sonarqube 3.7 installed. I configured the sonar jenkins plugin and it works well. I have Maven 3.0.3 and am using sonar maven plugin 2.1.

The problem is - it tries to execute the goal but asks for org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:jar:3.7. I cannot find this jar anywhere. In the repositories also, I can just see the pom for this and not the jar

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.1:sonar (default-cli) on project twister: Can not execute SonarQube analysis
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Can not execute SonarQube analysis
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:109)
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:67)
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:109)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:3.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:jar:3.7 in the local repository
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't be confused. There are 2 different plugins involved.

The first one is what we name "the Codehaus Sonar Mojo". This is the one you call when you do `mvn sonar:sonar`.
The GAV of this plugin is: `org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin`
We have recently released version 2.1 to support Maven 3.1. There are no frequent release of this plugin because we try to avoid any coupling with SonarQube version. When you call this plugin, it will simply do some basic checks, ask the SonarQube server for its version, then **bootstrap** the "SonarQube Maven plugin".

The "SonarQube Maven plugin" is a plugin that is released for each release of SonarQube server. The GAV of this plugin is: `org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven[3]-plugin`. In the past we used to need 2 different plugins (one for Maven 2, one for Maven 3). It was the job of the "Codehaus Sonar Mojo" to bootstrap the correct one according to Maven version. Starting from SonarQube server 3.7 there is only one plugin: `org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin`. To not break compatibility with the "Codehaus Sonar Mojo" that will still need to bootstrap `org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin` when you are using Maven 3+, then we have added a relocation pom at the old location.

As a sum up, here is what is expected when you start a SonarQube analysis with Maven 3+ and SonarQube server 3.7:

1. `mvn sonar:sonar`
2. Maven will download and use latest "Codehaus Sonar Mojo" ie `org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.1`
3. The "Codehaus Sonar Mojo" will query SonarQube server version and bootstrap `org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:3.7`
4. Maven will download pom of `org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:3.7` and see there is a relocation to `org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7`
5. Maven will download and use `org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7`

After this introduction, back to your issue. The message show that the "Codehaus Sonar Mojo" is not able to download `org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:3.7`. First you should try Marc suggestion and try to update your Maven version in case there is a bug with relocation support (I saw nothing about this in Maven release notes). Then you should check your Maven configuration (are you using a repository manager?).

Finally if you still have an issue please start with a clean Maven repository (backup/remove ~/.m2/repository) then run `mvn sonar:sonar -X` and complete your question with full logs.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. The problem indeed was that Maven was not able to download org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:3.7. After that, it correctly relocated to org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7. It works fine now.

Comment: @Abby, what exactly did you need to do to make it work? Upgrade Maven?

Comment: @Julien I'm having a similar problem; looks like SonarQube can't download the plugin in step 2.  I'm getting "Failure to find org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:jar:5.2".  Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

I have looked into pom file for `sonar-maven3-plugin` and looks like it has been relocated to `sonar-maven-plugin`

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-maven3-plugin/3.7/sonar-maven3-plugin-3.7.pom

pom says

```
Since Sonar 3.7 there is no more difference between Maven 2 and Maven 3 so relocate to Maven 2 plugin to avoid duplication
```

so I guess you can use sonar-maven-plugin instead of sonar-maven3-plugin.

Comment: How do I specify that? All I do is mention version 2.1 in maven-plugin version in jenkins. I tries to look up org.codehaus.mojo.sonar-maven-plugin.2.1  which it finds and then tries executing the goal, after which I get the above exception.

Comment: Don't be confused. There is no sonar-maven2-plugin and you should not try to use other plugin than `org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin`. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was using `mvn sonar:sonar`, which after an upgrade from Sonar 3.1 to 3.7 failed with exactly the same error message.

Turns out I was using an old version of Maven (3.0.1), which I guess did not handle this relocation of plugins correctly. **Upgrading** to **Maven 3.0.5 fixed the problem** for me.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if my diagnose is correct but it looks like:

- you used sonar some time ago so your maven downloaded all the plugins
- later they relocated some of their plugins so your downloaded plugins don't reflect the structure they expect right now (sounds ridiculous and exactly opposite to how maven supposed to work)

for me it helped to delete `~/.m2/repository/org/codehouse/mojo/sonar-maven-plugin` and `~/.m2/repository/org/codehouse/...` something else with sonar (i don't remember exactly)